# how to increase the slide size a python generated powerpoint presentation using python-pptx

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Am trying to fit multiple charts into a python generated slide but I need the size of the slide to be wider. I looked through the available documentation provided which aren't much.

Answer (score 11):

The default width and height for a slide generated by pptx is 10 inches width and 7.5 inches height. The following code will work to change its default slide width and height:

```py
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches


prs = Presentation()
# set width and height to 16 and 9 inches.
prs.slide_width = Inches(16)
prs.slide_height = Inches(9)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this by adjusting the width and height size of the prs

```py
prs = Presentation()
prs.slide_width = 11887200
prs.slide_height = 6686550
```

Comment: Also found that I could import inches measurement and use that instead of the above measurement point which can be confusing.