# creating a new pptx with python-pptx, and setting dimensions

Tags: python-pptx

I have a series of images that I want to consistently embed in a powerpoint document at the same position on the page.

I can do the image import piece, but I need the powerpoint dimensions to be specifiable by the user.

I think I can use the slide_height and slide_width. I'm trying code like this, to get a page 300mm high, but it isn't working:

`pack = Presentation(pptx=None)
 pack.slide_height(300)
pack.save('test.pptx')`

It throws a "TypeError: 'Emu' object is not callable" error.

I'm sure this is really obvious, but I can't see what the syntax should be, and the documentation isn't helping me. Would anyone be able to correct my code?

Many thanks,

Jeff.

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48604491/6064933

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Mm

prs = Presentation()
prs.slide_height = Mm(300)
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

In the [API documentation for `Presentation.slide_height`](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/presentation.html#pptx.presentation.Presentation.slide_height) you'll notice that `slide_height` is not followed by any parentheses (in contrast to `save()` just above it, for example). This indicates that `slide_height` is a *property* rather than a method, and is used by accessing it directly or assigning to it, like any other attribute.

The native unit of PowerPoint is the English Metric Unit (EMU), which is 1/914400th of an inch. These are described [in the documentation here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/autoshapes.html?highlight=english%20metric%20units#understanding-english-metric-units). 300 of these is a very short length indeed, which is what you would get if you assigned 300 to `slide_height` directly.

To allow you to skip the arithmetic, there are a variety of utility objects (like `Mm()` above) that allow EMU to be specified in common units, like centimeters and inches. Those are described [in the documentation here](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/util.html#pptx.util.Length).

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm moving from perl to python and sometimes trip over the syntax. Really helpful general case answer that explains a lot!